# Unable to connect bose soundlink AE2 headphones

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, bluetooth-speaker

this is my first question here, so sorry if there is something wrong about the rules.

I just installed Kubuntu 15.04 and i tried to connect my Bose headphones soundlink 2.
Bluedevil service reconize the headphone, but say "no supported service found" and my headphone tell me "ready to connect device".

I tried to connect bose soundlink Mini and it work fine.

`$pactl list short | grep bluetooth
 8       module-bluetooth-policy
 9       module-bluetooth-discover`

Thanks for helping.
Greg

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `pactl list short | grep bluetooth` thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way may help:

- install blueman `sudo apt-get install blueman`;
- connect the headphone using blueman;
- remove blue once the headphone is connected successfully, `sudo apt-get purge --remove blueman`.

Comment: How to use it @joseph ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago. I fixed it by upgrading my kernel to 3.19.0-50-generic.
Just do `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`

Comment: I updated my kernel. But it's not fixed it. My Bluetooth discovery found my headphone. But my bose don't detect the new connection. When i right click on bluetoot icone, and go on my device, it say "no supported services found"

Comment: @GregB. Did you solve this? Having the same problem.

Comment: Yes Stephen, I resolved it with Joseph's indication above, using blueman package.
I updated my distribution too, still working :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the instructions to solve this issue :) Just follow [this tutorial](https://erikdubois.be/installing-bose-ae2-soundlink-linux-mint-18/)

> Linux Mint 18 is equipped with the application `gnome-bluetooth`. This will be sufficient. If however you get into problems, you can always try the application `blueman` as well.
>
> This installation procedure also applies for Ubuntu 16.04.
>
> Make a new file
>
> ```
> sudo touch /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf
> ```
>
> Add these lines inside. Do not change anything. The order is important.
>
> ```
> [General]
> Disable=Socket
> Disable=Headset
> Enable=Media,Source,Sink,Gateway
> AutoConnect=true
> load-module module-switch-on-connect
> ```
>
> Now you will have to edit the file `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. Change the contents to this.
>
> ```
> # Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
> # is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
> # Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
> ControllerMode = bredr
> ```
>
> If you have just one Bluetooth toggle and you switch from computer all the time, change this line too. Change the code to this.
>
> ```
> # AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found. 
> # This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugged 
> # in later on. Defaults to 'false'. 
> AutoEnable=true
> ```
>
> Let the magic of rebooting be on your side. So reboot.
>
> Enable pairing on your headphones.
>
> Go to the Bluetooth icon, enable bluetooth and connect to your device.
>
> Go to the sound icon (bottom right) and select your device.
>
> See that the Output profile is High Fidelity Playback (A2DP sink). MUCH better sound than the other setting Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP). As long as you do not see this headphone in your sound settings, you guessed it, something is wrong. And in Bluetooth nothing seems that simple. Then you can start Googling. I suggest the [Arch Linux guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth) as a start.
>
> When all is working, do close this window as it will be glitching the music since it is scanning for other bluetooth devices.
>
> When you have been trying to add the Bluetooth device for a while, REMOVE IT and try again. That seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also can try to replace `PulseAudio` with the more modern `PipeWire`:

```
apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth && apt purge pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Then reboot.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676829/408419